# Prevent div from slideDown()

Tags: jquery, slideup

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/2sQGS/

It works fine, except I don't want the blurb box to slide down when I hover over it. I am guessing it's because I'm no longer hovering the block but I would like to deactivate the blurb box from any actions somehow.

Let me know if you need more information and thank you in advance for your time.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Check about http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to jQuery so hopefully someone else will soon come up with a better solution to your problem but what I would do (that worked) was to simply hold the .toggle-block and the .blurb inside another div.container block.

So you'll have this html structure:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="toggle-block"><img src="http://www.northareadevonfootball.co.uk/Images/football.jpg"></a>
        <div class="blurb">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Hello there, this is a test to take the content over one line so I can see what the line height looks like.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then you only change this to your jquery code:

```
$('.container').mouseleave(function() {
     $('.blurb').stop().slideUp(500);
});
```

it works... there are some things to improve though... let me know if you need more help and good luck with your project!

Comment: Yep Steven, that worked, but it's still not good.
Take a look at this new example: http://jsfiddle.net/YSMTN/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the box to stay there, remove the following lines and you're good:

```
    $('.toggle-block').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.blurb').stop().slideUp(500);
    });
```

If you want to hide the box when the mouse is no more on the ball, change these lines by the following :

```
    $('.toggle-block').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.blurb').stop().hide();
    });
```

Comment: then what should it do? I am confused

Comment: answer updated, is it what you want? otherwise, please clarify your question

Comment: I want it to slideUp when I hover over it and slideDown when I'm not. Simple as that - although I don't want the blurb to over-ride override the toggle-block.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is what you want

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var check = true;                   
        $('.toggle-block').mouseenter(function() {
            if(check){
            $(this).siblings('.blurb').slideDown(1000);
                check = false;
            }
        });

        $('.toggle-block').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.blurb').stop().slideUp(500);
        });

    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: Then I dont get your question can you please clarify it

Comment: It's not mine... anyway he wants to that div with the text will slide down only if he's leaving the image location.

Comment: Then add the  $(this).siblings('.blurb').slideDown(1000); to your mouseleave function and remove the mouseenter function